# Passing array into function, want the original unmodified array afterward

Tags: sml

I have a function that, as a side-effect, mutates an array that's passed in:

```
fun do_something (n: int, v: bool array) =
       let 
          val i = ref 0
          val count = ref 0
       in while !i < n do
          ( if Array.sub (v, !i) then 
               Array.update (v, !i, false)
            else
               (count := !count + 1); 
            i := !i + 1
          );
          !count
       end
```

When the function has ended I want the array to have its original contents again. How can I do that?

Comment: I made an edit hope that helps

Comment: I basicly need for example, to use an array into a function, meaning maybe change its values inside the function but when the function has ended i want the array to have stayed the same

Comment: It sounds to me like you're going to have to copy the array as some point.

Comment: Thats what I am doing, but i want to know if there is a more efficient way

Comment: If you're only modifying a small subset of the array it might be more space efficient to only store the deltas and restore them at the end, but I wonder if given you actual use case, something other than an array is the right choice.

Comment: made some edits hope I am more specific

Comment: So I think that your use case is that you have an array which you *don't* want to change but that you want to compute something based on the array (maybe a Boolean value) and that your algorithm for computing the return value involves mutating the array. If so, the best solution is to get a better algorithm. Perhaps something which is purely functional. If that isn't possible or is too inefficient, make a local copy. I don't think that there is any third way.

Comment: In your example, there's no reason for your function to mutate the array if you don't want it to. It never re-examines an element after modifying it.

Comment: Its just an example, its not that function the problem

Comment: In the general case, if you have to store the information, well, you have to store the information (and thus need somewhere to store it). Without knowing the specifics of you actual use case, it's hard to say if you actually need to store extra information.